# Does ERC-1155 contract use less gas to mint tokens?

Tags: gas, nft, mint

The commonly accepted benefit of using ERC-1155 (than ERC-721) is it saves lots of gas. But does it actually save gas when minting tokens?

If so, should we pre-mint tokens when the contract is deployed? I wonder how OpenSea does it.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it actually save gas when minting tokens

Yes it can save a a lot of gas when minting tokens. Lets look at the example below where I have created two simple OpenZeppelin contracts. One is an ERC721 and one is a ERC1155.

When I deploy these functions and mint I get the following results:

- Minting with an ERC721 costs 96,073 gas
- Minting with an ERC1155 costs 51,935 gas

So you can see that in this basic case the ERC721 is costing almost double to mint. It's also important to note that implementations can vary significantly which changes the gas prices.

The reason ERC1155s are generally cheaper is because they have a more efficient method for storing data.

> should we pre-mint tokens when the contract is deployed

This would depend on your use case. If you are deploying a 10k NFT collection it is probably not a good idea to mint all the NFTs yourself. Instead a common pattern being used at the moment is allowing people to mint the NFTs themselves via your website.

> I wonder how OpenSea does it

OpenSea uses a method called [LazyMinting](https://blog.opensea.io/announcements/introducing-the-collection-manager/). Where you upload all the metadata but you dont actually put the NFT on-chain until a user mints the NFT. This allows you to upload NFTs without paying any fees. This is also similar to having a mint function on your website in the sense that in both cases the end user who wants the NFT pays for the cost of minting. This solution scales well.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";


contract MyERC721 is ERC721, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "MTK") {}

    function safeMint(address to, uint256 tokenId, string memory uri)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }
}

contract MyERC1155 is ERC1155, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC1155("") {}

    function setURI(string memory newuri) public onlyOwner {
        _setURI(newuri);
    }

    function mint(address account, uint256 id, uint256 amount, bytes memory data)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        _mint(account, id, amount, data);
    }

    function mintBatch(address to, uint256[] memory ids, uint256[] memory amounts, bytes memory data)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        _mintBatch(to, ids, amounts, data);
    }
}
```